# How to make a Linear Compass in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, app-inventor

I'm trying to learn App Inventor 2, by implementing the tutorials and redo some in another way. I'm currently trying to make a compass similar to [this](https://code.google.com/p/puravidaapps/downloads/detail?name=compass.aia), but instead of the classic rotating disk, I want to have a linear display, something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cactusreach.linearcompass).

Should the code blocks used in the rotating compass be altered in a way, to have the linear compass effect? By simply changing the displaying image does not work.

I'm currently using this block combination:

"when OrientationSensor1.OrientationChanged
do set Compass.Heading to get azimuth +180 (to get N always)"

Can someone give me a clue on how to implement a working linear compass in app Inventor 2, if it is possible? Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw one yourself using the canvas.

Check this example how to render it, it draws the North mark only, but you can extend it easily to draw all other marks...

Before use I would try if this approach (redrawing the old position of marks) is not slower of faster than clearing the whole canvas (might perform faster).

Good luck.
[image: HorizontalCompass blocks]

Comment: Hello @MirecXP. Frankly, didn't expect someone to respond to this post, so I thank u. Meanwhile, I've implemented a digital compass version naming the cardinals (N,S,E,W) in a text label. Glad you answered, so I can follow up with your approach to make my app. I've already recreated your suggested blocks and "N" is coming up as a letter in canvas. You didn't mention your designing approach, I've used a canvas and a label outside of canvas. I needed to have a graphic with the cardinals to move according to direction (see this in my question). so how can this be done in the canvas?

Comment: Draw the cardinals just as a text inside the canvas. You need just the canvas and the orientation sensor objects in the design part.

Comment: To use some cardinal graphics instead of simple text, you can insert the image sprites into the canvas and call spriteN.MoveTo(x,y) in the drawCompass procedure, use some fixed y and calculated position for the x of sprite. But it won't display partially if drawn near the edge, but it will remain always fully visible. To have it drawn preciselly on the edge, you can shrink the drawing area of the compass little bit.